# How to use spark sql string function in when then function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to change the language column's value if the text column has english text So I have use when-then function but its not able to evaluate the ascii spark string function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newdf = df.withColumn("asc", ascii("text"))
      .withColumn("language", when(col("asc") > 0, "en")
      .otherwise(col("hi")))
```

Even tried

```
    val newdf = df.withColumn("language", when(ascii(col("asc")) > 0, "en")
          .otherwise(col("hi")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function "ascii" parameter have to be column (not string), and in "otherwise" string have to be specified:

```
val newdf = df.withColumn("asc", ascii($"text"))
  .withColumn("language", when(col("asc") > 0, "en")
    .otherwise("hi"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the issue is you are mixing column-name and column at few places. Below code will give the correct result :

```
 df.withColumn("language", when(ascii(col("text")) > 0, "en").otherwise("hi"))
```

Comment: what is the difference to pasha701 answer?

Comment: difference is you don't need to create a new column "asc".

Comment: how to access first element of array in ascii(col("text[0]"))?

Comment: @happy you can explode the array to make a new column and pass it to the ascii function.